# JSON Array Loop Inserting into Android SQLite Database

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, loops

I have the following snippet the loops through a JSON Array and inserts the data into a database.  My problem is that it's not inserting all the records.  If I have 6 records it will only inserts 5 of the 6.  If I have 5 records it will only insert 4?  When I debug the storesArray.length it shows the total records in the array as 6.  What I'm I doing wrong that it won't loop and insert all the records in the array?

Here's the SQL String that's coming in from the server:

```
[{"id":"29","cId":"3","sName":"Milford Plaza Hotel","sNumber":"3061","sCustNm":"VS7997","sSalesman":"1234","sAddress":"","sContact":"","sPhone":""},{"id":"26","cId":"7","sName":"Circle K Bowling Green","sNumber":"5670","sCustNm":"VS7976","sSalesman":"1234","sAddress":"1091 N Main Street\r\nBowling Green, Ohio 43402","sContact":"","sPhone":""},{"id":"25","cId":"7","sName":"Circle K Bowling Green","sNumber":"5669","sCustNm":"VS7975","sSalesman":"1234","sAddress":"966 S Main Street\r\nBowling Green, OH 43402","sContact":"","sPhone":""},{"id":"22","cId":"6","sName":"Rock Branch Exxon","sNumber":"122","sCustNm":"VS7983","sSalesman":"1234","sAddress":"Rt 1 Box 34 A\r\nPoca, W.V.","sContact":"","sPhone":""},{"id":"23","cId":"6","sName":"Marathon Food Mart","sNumber":"156","sCustNm":"VS7984","sSalesman":"1234","sAddress":"2300 Pike Street\r\nParkerburg, W.V.","sContact":"Jenny","sPhone":""},{"id":"27","cId":"7","sName":"Circle K Dayton","sNumber":"5346","sCustNm":"VS7992","sSalesman":"1234","sAddress":"816 Waterveilt Ave\r\nDayton, OH 45420","sContact":"","sPhone":""}]
```

JSONArray storesArray = new JSONArray(restults);

```
        for(int i = 0; i < storesArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject store = storesArray.getJSONObject(i);

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO stores ( sId, cId, sName, sAddress, sNumber, sSalesman, sCustNum, sPhone ) " +
                        "VALUES ('"+store.getString("id")+"', '"+store.getString("cId")+"', '"+store.getString("sName")+"', '"+store.getString("sAddress")+"', '"+store.getString("sNumber")+"', '"+store.getString("sSalesman")+"', '"+store.getString("sCustNm")+"', '"+store.getString("sPhone")+"' )");

        }
```

Comment: please also post the sql code that ypu pass to `execSQL`

Comment: I've added it to the above snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `store.getString("id")` should be your primary column ID? You shouldn't define that in an insert query, the database will do that for you.

More important: **Don't put strings directly in your query** since this is a great way to destroy your query (called SQL injection)

Do something like that:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO stores ( sId, cId, sName, sAddress, sNumber, sSalesman, sCustNum, sPhone ) " +
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    new Object [] {
        store.getString("cId"),
        store.getString("sName"),
        store.getString("sAddress"),
        store.getString("sNumber"),
        store.getString("sSalesman"),
        store.getString("sCustNm"),
        store.getString("sPhone")});
```

Comment: The store.getString("id") is not my primary id.  It's used for referencing.  It relates to the sId in the new table that is getting creating in the SQLite database.  However, I will use your solution for inserting the data into the database.  Thanks for that.  Any help on my original question would be great.